# What would cause named to send out hundreds of bogus responses?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, linux-networking, attacks

My DNS server running RHEL 6.6 is actively sending unsolicited DNS responses to a couple of IP's. By unsolicited I mean that there is no incoming request from the external IP, the DNS server seems to want to talk to this external host for some reason on its own and I cant figure out why. Netstat shows the outbound connections tied to the named process. tcpdump confirms these are mostly outbound. They look like this: (the hostnames at the end are whats in the actual tcpdump)

```
104115 5.888666   <DNS server source IP> <dest IP>   DNS 80 Standard query 0xfc38 A chhveu.x99moyu.net
```

There are tons of these: Here is another example:

```
104012 5.8884459  <DNS server source IP> <dest IP>  DNS 106 Standard query 0x688b MX 3636.3335.3338.3737.80h423333324d.host.com
```

Again, tons of these.

I have been able to get this under control by using iptables. However the packet counters are increasing at a rapid pace so I know the named service is still wanting to talk to this IP. Another strange thing I noticed is after putting the iptables rule in place. I blocked the IP using the INPUT chain first, and continued to see traffic. Then I added the IP to the OUTPUT chain, and the incoming request seemed to immediately dry up, while the outbound request keep adding up. So I fear the incoming request were actually being produced by the outgoing request. Here is what packet counters look like in iptables:

Input Chain:

```
4   292 DROP       all  --  any    any     X.X.X.X/24     anywhere
```

Output chain:

```
41174 4514K DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere   x.x.x.x/24
```

Could this systeme be compromised and if so, is there anything I can do to remediate it?

Comment: A query for an MX record is usually linked to mail handling. Do your server have an open relay? How are the email log files?

Comment: I will have to check. It should not be open. I still  do not see how that would cause these requests to originate from the DNS server without an initial query incoming. My first example was also an A record response.

Comment: If there's lots of mail messages waiting on queue, your mail server may be trying reverse lookups, and asking named about the IP addresses. It would explain a lot of DNS requests made by named.

Comment: I can see that. However I would expect to see queries for valid hostnames, not that gibberish I am seeing. A query for this - 3636.3335.3338.3737.80h423333324d.host.com does not look normal. Would you agree?

Comment: It's pretty normal, actually. A `EHLO 3636.3335.3338.3737.80h423333324d.host.com` is a perfect normal SMTP command...

Comment: These are DNS queries, not responses. Unless you're running a caching server, queries would not be sent as a result of receiving other queries, they're sent as a result of applications on the machine looking up names.